# Reissuing AD certificate breaks Always On VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, pki, microsoft

Reissuing AD certificate breaks Always On VPN.

We needed to update our AD CA to have a longer key length and an improved signing algorithm.

This works fine and we are able to issue new certificates while previously issued certificates continue to be valid.

The problem we have is when it comes to our Microsoft Always On VPN.

We initially requested new client VPN certs issued using our new CA cert.  When we did this, the AOVPN would no longer connect. The error is "Couldn't connect because we couldn't find a certificate for single sign on..."

We found on the client machine that a file called rasphone.pbk contains a string with CA certs's thumbprint in it. So we updated this (by directly editing the file) to the thumbprint of our new CA cert.

We restarted the client and retried and received the error "The parameter is incorrect".

We reset all of the networking on the client machine, but the error persisted.

Has anyone ever done this before? And what was your process?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might missed the step to update the SSL Certificate Binding in the VPN server.

https://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2022/02/10/always-on-vpn-sstp-certificate-renewal/

Comment: Thanks for the input! I think the link refers to the extrenal cert issued by a public CA? I do have an NPS and a the Radius (VPN) server that we did not reissue internal machine certs on, we wonder if maybe that was the issue? But we looked at the event logs on those servers and didn't see any events related to connection attaempts which made us thing our problem is on the client, what do you think? Is there any published procedure anywhere for this activity?

Comment: I think it's important to verify that the VPN server and the SSTP binding has a valid and trusted certificate.